# Retornando quantidade de registros do Sqlite e exibindo em TextView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tenho uma aplicação e preciso exibir em um `TextView` a quantidade de registros armazenados.

```
public int contagem(){
    createBank = new CreateBank(this);
    connecting = createBank.getReadableDatabase();
    String cursor = "SELECT * FROM "+TABELA;
    int contador = connecting.rawQuery(cursor, null).getCount();
    TextView txtContagem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContagem);
    txtContagem.setText(contador);
    return contador;
}

2018-10-24 17:09:20.221 30170-30170/com.example.leandroramos.qualidade E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.leandroramos.qualidade, PID: 30170
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.leandroramos.qualidade.Qualidade.WorkSpace.contagem(WorkSpace.java:216)
    at com.example.leandroramos.qualidade.Qualidade.WorkSpace$1.onClick(WorkSpace.java:148)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24717)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6568)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando? O que acontece? Mas veja se não é isso: txtContagem.setText( String.valueOf(contador) para converter para texto;;

Comment: Continua com o erro, ele não dá nada como saída só fecha o aplicativo.

Comment: É o tipo de erro que ninguém vai conseguir lhe ajudar só olhando o código. Edite sua pergunta colando nela o _log_ da _exception_ que estourou e ocasionou o fechamento da sua aplicação. Fica como dica também: ao tomar um erro, a primeira coisa a fazer é debugar a aplicação para localizar o ponto de falha. Só a partir daí é que você vai em busca de solução.

Comment: Coloque um ponto de interrupção e veja qual traz em "contador" e em "cursor". Vá depurando e veja em que linha dá erro.

Comment: Fui depurando e o erro foi apresentado na linha txtContagem.setText(String.ValueOf(contador));

Comment: Qual erro a IDE informa? Veja na aba Logcat ou mesmo Console e cole na sua postagem.

Comment: Incrementei o erro que informa no logcat.

Comment: Depure e veja se `txtContagem` está nulo e veja também qual o valor da variável `contador`.